# How to write q series using array environment

Tags: pdftex, arrays

I would like to code in latex, please guide me

[image]

I tried this code,
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}
q^2, q^8 \
q^3, q^{7} ; q^{10}
\end{array}\right)_{\infty}$$ but I want the base q^{10} to be in the middle not in the second row

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us what you've tried so far. And, is it important to employ a Times Roman math font?

Comment: Is this in connection with hypergeometric functions?

Comment: @egreg Yes this related to hypergeometric functions, specially q series with quotient of q products with more than one parameter

Comment: @Mico I tried this code, $$\left(\begin{array}{c} q^2, q^8 \ q^3, q^{7} ; q^{10} \end{array}\right)_{\infty}$$ but this is giving me the base q^{10} in the second row. I want it to be in the middle of those two rows as shown in the figure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A modification of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125531/4427

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newmuskip\pFqmuskip

\NewDocumentCommand{\qseriesinner}{mmmmm}{%
  \begingroup % only local assignments
  \pFqmuskip=#5mu\relax
  \mathchardef\normalcomma=\mathcode`,
  % make the comma math active
  \mathcode`\,=\string"8000
  % and define it to be \pFqcomma
  \begingroup\lccode`\~=`\,
  \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\pFqcomma
  % typeset the formula
  {\left(\genfrac..{0pt}{}{#1}{#2};#3\right)\IfValueT{#4}{_{\!#4}}}%
  \endgroup
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\pFq}{mmmmme{_}O{8}}{%
  {}_{\kern-\scriptspace#1}F_{#2\kern-\scriptspace}
  \qseriesinner{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\qseries}{mmme{_}O{8}}{%
  \qseriesinner{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
}
\newcommand{\pFqcomma}{{\normalcomma}\mskip\pFqmuskip}

\begin{document}

\[
\qseries{q^2,q^8}{q^3,q^7}{q^{10}}_{\infty}
\qquad
\qseries{q^2,q^8}{q^3,q^7}{q^{10}}_{\infty}[3]
\]

\[
\pFq{3}{2}{a,b,c}{d,e}{z}_{\infty}
\qquad
\pFq{3}{2}{a,b,c}{d,e}{z}[4]
\qquad
\textstyle\pFq{3}{2}{a,b,c}{d,e}{z}
\]

\end{document}
```

The arguments should be self-explaining: the trailing optional argument sets the space after commas.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that nests a `matrix` environment inside a `pmatrix` environment. (The code for both environments is provided by the `amsmath` package.) The expression on the left contains "raw" code, without spacing tweaks. The expression on the right applies some spacing-related fine-tuning adjustments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'matrix' and 'pmatrix' environments
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
  \begin{matrix} 
    q^2,q^8 \\ q^3,q^7
  \end{matrix}
; q^{10}
\end{pmatrix}_{\infty}
\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}
  \begin{matrix} 
    q^2,q^8 \\ q^3,q^7
  \end{matrix}
\,; q^{10}\!
\end{pmatrix}_{\!\infty}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal centering is achieved via `\multicolumn{2}{c}`, while vertical centering is obtained via `\raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}`

Solution is base on: [Combining rows and columns in array](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153225/combining-rows-and-columns-in-array)
 by Werner

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$$
    \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
       q^2 & q^8 &  &  \\
       q^3 & q^7 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\smash{\raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}{$q^{10}$}}}
    \end{array}\right)_\infty
$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this solution insert commas and semicolons (which are displayed in original query)?